# How can print raw escape characters as \t and \n in cout?

Tags: c++, cout

how can print escape characters without further processing and as `\t` or `\n` or ... in `std::cout`?
I dont want to process text manually before sending it to output?
Is there any switch to `std::cout` for this purpose?

Comment: The escape characters only exist in the source code – the string itself contains the actual characters that the escape characters represent.

Comment: Okay, escape characters exist in source code , and std::cout receives this string that already contains escape sequences!

Comment: @molbdnilo I think the point is how to get output streams to stream the "raw" representation of these characters.

Comment: @vahedmafi You may lookup for raw string literals. However there's no way to change the mode of `std::ostream` to ignore excaped characters.

Comment: @vahedmafi The string does not contain escape sequences. If you want to print whitespace characters as something other than whitespace you need to handle it yourself.

Comment: Finally , I found the solution: Raw Strings, see below

Comment: @vahedmafi Note that in "raw strings", the backslash is not an escape character. The raw string `R"\n"` is equivalent to `"\\n"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically a raw string literal is a string in which the escape characters (like \n \t or \" ) of C++ are not processed. A raw string literal starts with R"( and ends in )", let's see it in an example the difference between a normal string and a raw string in C++:

```
string raw_str=R"(First line.\nSecond line.\nEnd of message.\n)";
cout<<raw_str<<endl;
```

result:

```
~$ ./a.out
First line.\nSecond line.\nEnd of message.\n
```

Comment: How can I make a string raw at runtime?

Answer (score -3):

If you add one extra slash there as \\t you can see \t in the output of std::cout

For example: cout<<"\\t hello" will print \t hello.

I hope this helps

Comment: I don't want to process text manually before sending to std::cout.