# Console output of strings with special characters

Tags: c++, c, formatted

Is there a more or less standard way to output character strings that contain special characters, such ASCII control codes, in such a way that the output is a valid C/C++ literal string, with escape sequences ?

Example of expected output: `This\nis\na\\test\n\nShe said, \"How are you?\"\n`

Without care, the output would be

```
This
is
a\test

She said, "How are you?"
```

not what  want.

Comment: Please don't tag such questions with C and C++ simultaneously. These are different language, have different strategies for IO etc. Decide which one you want to have.

Comment: @JensGustedt: I am accepting answers for both languages, solutions from both worlds can do. AFAIK, there are few syntactical differences between C and C++ string literals.

Comment: If it is string literals in the program, you can escape the escape characters `"This\\nis\\n"` to actually have `\n` stored in the string. Otherwise probably not.

Comment: Never mind, you are just talking about ASCII formatting. C `printf` (family) and C++ `iostream` shouldn't have any problems with actual "string" contents. (my earlier comment related to ANSI escapes)

Comment: @BoPersson: no, the string is not in the code, it is data.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: these I/O statements will not produce the expected output.

Comment: Where do these IO statements come from? Literals? Library user/file input functions? Pipes? Sockets?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: array of char

Comment: As long as you can *nul-terminate* the array, you should be able to use it in either `printf` or `cout`. I have no issues with the following `printf ("This\nis\na\\test\n\nShe said, \"How are you?\"\n");` If your array of char contains a *nul-terminated* string, then simple `printf (ptr_to_your_array);` works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can print raw escape characters as \t and \n in cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843417/how-can-print-raw-escape-characters-as-t-and-n-in-cout)

Comment: Just use the c++11's [raw string](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#raw-strings), if I correctly understood your question.

Comment: @ZDF: no, this is a syntax for compile-time. I am outputing data.

Comment: @moooeeeep: my question is different, but the `edit` link doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: no, read my post. This is precisely what I want to avoid. (God, I know about printf !)

Comment: Well, I figured you did, but you question left me, and quite a few others, scratching our collective heads about just what it was you were trying to achieve. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you might be trying to achieve I can suggest the following solution: Just replace any non-printable character with "\xnn" (nn being the ascii code of the character. This would boil down to

```
void myprint (char *s) {
   while (*s) {
      printf(isalnum((unsigned char) *s) ? "%c" : "\\%03hho", *s);
      s++;
   }
}
```

This will of course not use special abbreviations like `\n` (but `\x0a`) instead, but this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yep, this is what I need. I wanted to know if there is no more standard stuff, but apparently not. I have added code to handle the escapes.

Comment: Minor improvement: `isalnum((unsigned char) *s)` to handle pesky negative `*s`. and `"\\x%02x"` --> `"\\x%02hhx"`

Comment: @YvesDaoust  characters like `'!'` and `'?'` *are* printable, but are replaced, using this function. Do you consider those as "special" too?

Comment: @Bob__: no I don't. I don't know how to name these characters. Non-printable doesn't work, because the backslash is printable but must be escaped.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Well, if so, I don't understand wht you don't use [`iscntrl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/iscntrl)...

Comment: This approach does not work if a special character is followed by a hex-digit that is part of the string. E.g `"?a"` will be printed as `"\x3fa"` which will be read as one single character code at the other end.

Comment: @JensGustedt: you are quite right. I see this as a bug in the C++ specification. As Ctx also said, octal is an answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, why would that be a bug? It is just a constraint that you have to take into account.

Comment: @JensGustedt: it is a poor design decision, which precludes the safe mixture of numerical escapes and printing characters, as there is no end delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Printing escaped strings clearly is tricky.

Problems include

1. Control characters and the *null character*.
2. Escaping the escape character.
3. Negative `char`.
4. Hexadecimal escape sequence have no specified limit in length.  Octal ones are limited to 3 digits.

   ```
   void EscapePrint(char ch) {
     // 1st handle all simple-escape-sequence C11 6.4.4.4
     // The important one to detect is the escape character `\`
     // Delete or adjust these 2 arrays per code's goals
     static const char *escapev = "\a\b\t\n\v\f\r\"\'\?\\";
     static const char *escapec = "abtnvfr\"\'\?\\";
     char *p = strchr(escapev, (unsigned char) ch);
     if (p && *p) {
       printf("\\%c", escapec[p - escapev]);
     }

     // if printable, just print it.
     else if (isprint((unsigned char) ch)) {
       fputc(ch, stdout);
     }

     // else use octal escape  
     else {
       // Use octal as hex is problematic reading back
       printf("\\%03hho", ch);
     }
   }
   ```

Pedantic: the octal escape sequence is a problem on rare machines whose `char` range exceeds 9 bits.  This can be handled with a hex escaped sequences at the *string* level and not on a `char` by `char` basis as hex escaped sequences need a limit.  Example:

```
  input 2 `char`:            \1 A
  //                               v----- intervening space
  output text including ":   "\\x1" "A"
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that this string interruption also terminates the hex value ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes.  In C source, with `char s[] = "\xB" "ABC\0004\1";`, `s` becomes an array 8 of `char` with values of 11, 'A', 'B', 'C', 0, '4', 1, 0 for example.  The 2 portions of the _string literal_ are merged together, yet the hexadecimal escape sequence ends with `"`.

Comment: @chus: I did not find information about that; one can wonder if the parsing of the string is made before or after pasting.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps someone, I have quickly put this together:

```
void printfe(char* string)
{
    for (char c= *string; c; c= *(++string))
    {
        switch (c)
        {
        case '\a': printf("\\a"); break;
        case '\b': printf("\\b"); break;
        case '\f': printf("\\f"); break;
        case '\n': printf("\\n"); break;
        case '\r': printf("\\r"); break;
        case '\t': printf("\\t"); break;
        case '\v': printf("\\v"); break;
        case '\\': printf("\\\\"); break;
        case '\'': printf("\\\'"); break;
        case '\"': printf("\\\""); break;
        case '\?': printf("\\?"); break;
        default: (c < ' ' || c > '~') ? printf("\\%03o", c) : putchar(c); break;
        }
    }
}
```

(mind the potential non-portability of `c < ' ' || c > '~'`, I wanted to avoid any library reference).

Comment: This approach does not work if a special character is followed by a hex-digit that is part of the string. E.g `"\015a"` will be printed as `"\x0da"` which will be read as one single character code at the other end.

Comment: Also this implicitly implies that the coding is ASCII. But then all the special cases that are listed in the `switch` statement with never trigger.

Comment: @JensGustedt: I have changed to octal escapes. I don't mind the non- portability.

Comment: Still your whole series of cases is completely useless.

Comment: Many platforms use a _signed_ `char`.  `char c = -1;
    printf("\\%03o", c);` may print `"\37777777777"`.  Best to insure a `char` is passed as `unsigned char` or use `"\\%03hho"`.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I meant useless in the sense that your `switch` will never trigger these. So it is not only useless to me, but to the compiler.

Comment: For completeness: "care about the special escapes" --> `\a` (alert) is one of the standard alphabetic escape sequences (5.2.2) not in your `switch()`.

Comment: @chux: right, thanks to spotting the typo. I said "quickly put" ;-)

Comment: Yves, @jens is right that the `if() .. else` would benefit with review.  Many of the cases will not get used as `if (c < ' '` will certainly catch them before the `switch(c)`

Comment: @chux: I must really have been drowsy this morning .

Comment: Apologies to @jensgusted.

Comment: @YvesDaoust There readily is some deep C languages issues not noticed at first blush.  If this output is to feed into a `*.c` file and compile, then we should look at various spec concerns about characters like `$` - but that is for highly portable code and appears to [beyond the goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46727567/console-output-of-strings-with-special-characters/46728245?noredirect=1#comment80404590_46728245).